# LibreOffice Calc clears clipboard

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

My use case is: I am running Chrome and filling in a web form. For one text box that I need to fill, I need to get the data from a spreadsheet. So I open the spreadsheet using LibreOffice Calc, copy the data, then close it and try to paste into the web form. Unfortunately, at that point, I find out that closing Calc has caused the clipboard to be cleared. Other applications don't do that. Is there a way to tell LibreOffice not to clear the clipboard when I exit the application?

(I know a simple workaround is to not exit Calc, but I am in the habit of closing applications as soon as I no longer need them, and this is what I do when I paste from other applications.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed in the report
[Bug 48783 - Summary: Clipboard cleared on exit on Linux](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48783),
where a user named Yousuf Philips (jay) has answered:

> After reading through the links provided on this page, the ubuntu clipboard persistence page has stated that a user can solve this issue for libreoffice and all other applications by installing a clipboard manager. It recommends parcellite, but mentions alternatives for xfce (clipman), KDE (klipper) and Gnome (glipper) desktop environments.

This issue isn't really a LibreOffice issue, but depends on
your window manager. Installing a clipboard manager will solve it.